# cloned Windows Server on VMware IIS Problems

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization

I've been converting a physical windows server 2008 as Virtual Machine on ESXI and I was trying to enable under Server Manager an ftp connection. Having problem to set up IIS properly I thought I'm going to reinstall all Roles, but than WSUS at a point is stopping to work. Checking my windowsUpdate.log I can see the following

```
Update is not allowed to download due to regulation

Regulation: {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D} - Update 7CF1F0A7-11C6-4C99-9931-9A564835026F is "PerUpdate" regulated and can NOT download. Sequence 1939 vs AcceptRate 0.
```

What does it mean?

Comment: What is your actual problem that you're looking to solve? Is there a problem with the P2V? A problem with FTP? Or do you want to know how to resolve the WSUS error that you're getting? Also, is WSUS on the same server that you converted, or is it on another server?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Actually I would like to know how to fix WSUS error and I think all my problems would be solved. The converted windows server is on another server.

Answer (score 1):

'Update is not allowed to download due to regulation' means that Microsoft is throttling your download and you need to try later.  If you need to update your server sooner than later, you may download and apply the updates manually.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. On update I get the folowing error when it tries to Update Windows Server Update Services 3.0 SP2(KB2720211) WindowsUpdate_00000643 error